# Cannot establish connection - source does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, jsplumb

I have a simple section in which users can connect from one element to another element as they wish. after connection can be like this. am using jsPlumb for connections.

[image]

After connections, if the user is satisfied he/she can save it,

everything is saved correctly as I want, now when user reload the page connections eg (con_6, con_18) are not displayed.

Here is json where the data are saved.

```
{
    "movies": [
        {
            "left": 237,
            "top": 99,
            "movieid": "51"
        },
        {
            "left": 241,
            "top": 263,
            "movieid": "10"
        },
        {
            "left": 746,
            "top": 184,
            "movieid": "12"
        }
    ],
    "connections": [
        {
            "buttonid": "0",
            "movieid": "12"
        },
        {
            "buttonid": "4",
            "movieid": "12"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my function to load my connections

```
$.getJSON('datasaved/settings2.json', function (data) {

        var flowchartconnection =data.connections;

        for( var j = 0; j < flowchartconnection.length; j++ ) {

            console.log(flowchartconnection[j].buttonid);

            jsPlumb.connect({ source: flowchartconnection[j].buttonid, target: flowchartconnection[j].movieid });
            console.log(jsPlumb.connect);


        }


    });
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

> Cannot establish a connection - source does not exist.

Here is live demo :[live demo](https://videomill-bot.audiencevideo.com/editor/?settings2)

Here is js plumb connect function documentation: [js plumb connect](https://community.jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/connect-examples.html)

Here is my console.log  from my live demo : [live demo](https://videomill-bot.audiencevideo.com/editor/)

[image]

As you can see on the console the source and target id is available on the  DOM before the connections happen,

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: Can not establish a connection - source does not exist, you can see it yourself in console.