# jsPlumb.getConnections not working

Tags: jsplumb

UPDATED: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/janessaallen/c3b514wf/7/

Trying to figure out why the following will not get my jsplumb connections. I have a separate flowchart save javascript file with the following function for saving:

```
    function saveFlowchart() {
    var nodes = []

    $(".window").each(function (idx, elem) {
        var $elem = $(elem);
        var endpoints = jsPlumb.getEndpoints($elem.attr('id'));
        nodes.push({
            id: $elem.attr('id'),
            text: $elem.find($(".beneficiary")).text(),
            positionX: parseInt($elem.css("left"), 10),
            positionY: parseInt($elem.css("top"), 10)
        });
    });
    var connections = [];

    $.each(jsPlumb.getConnections(), function (idx, connection) {
            connections.push({
            connectionId: connection.id,
            sourceId: connection.sourceId,
            targetId: connection.targetId,
            anchors: $.map(connection.endpoints, function (endpoint) {

                return [[endpoint.anchor.x,
                endpoint.anchor.y,
                endpoint.anchor.orientation[0],
                endpoint.anchor.orientation[1],
                endpoint.anchor.offsets[0],
                endpoint.anchor.offsets[1]]];

            })
        });
    });

    var flowChart = {};
    flowChart.nodes = nodes;
    flowChart.connections = connections;
}
```

The endpoints work fine and get pushed to the array, but none of the connections are discovered by jsPlumb.getConnections.

Comment: code looks fine. Create a fiddle demonstrating the issue. What does `jsPlumb.getAllConnections` return ?

Comment: try changing `getConnections()` to `getAllConnections()`

Comment: Hi, thank you. getAllConnections() does not work. Not sure how to even start with the fiddle for jsplumb...???

Comment: This is basically what I am trying to accomplish: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620719/save-and-load-jsplumb-flowchart-including-exact-anchors-and-connections

Comment: Thanks. But I cannot get the connections. That is the only part that is missing. The connections won't be pushed to the array.

Comment: I updated my code to reflect more about what I am trying to do.

Comment: what version of `jsPlumb` are you using ? The link you mentioned contains a working `jsfiddle`. I am also working on a similar project - https://github.com/coding-idiot/jsPlumb-Persistence/blob/master/jsplumb-persistence-plugin.js

Comment: Thanks. I just grabbed the latest version from the site last week. I'll check out your link and see if it may solve my connection issue.

Comment: Nope, can't get the connection populated with getAllConnections().

Comment: It recognizes 'jsPlumb' but doesn't grab the connections. Just to clarify, if I draw them right on the page using the tool (by hand), shouldn't it recognize the connection in the DOM?

Comment: unless you can create a fiddle demonstrating the issue, I guess I'm out of possible reasons.

Comment: I'm going to try to do that this weekend. It wouldn't let me add any libraries when last I tried. Stay tuned...

Comment: `http://bit.ly/1vCbsRD` take any of these. Clone & make your changes.

Comment: I have the fiddle updated and posted in the original question.

Comment: @coding_idiot please can u check this https://github.com/nitinsurana/jsPlumb-Persistence/issues/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An instance of `jsPlumb` is created to create connections/makeSources/makeTargets, rather than using the global variable `jsPlumb` itself.

If an instance is used to create connections, then **it has to be queried** not the `jsPlumb` global variable.

I've updated the fiddle to save a reference to instance & used the `instance to getAllConnections.`

Updated fiddle    http://jsfiddle.net/c3b514wf/8/

Comment: Thanks! Getting closer, but it's still not recognizing the instance.

Comment: The issue is now the endpoints of the connections. So I will mark this as the answer. I will continue to troubleshoot the rest, but thank you so much for your help!